# Quadratic Form: sum of quadrants, diagonalization and e.t.c

Tags: linear-algebra, abstract-algebra, diagonalization, quadratic-forms, bilinear-form

I have the quadratic form

$$q\left(x_1,\:x_2,\:x_3,x_4\right)=2x_1x_4-6x_2x_3$$

$q:\:R^4-R^4$

I need to :

1. express it as a sum of quadrants
2. find a base B of $R^4$ in which q is diagonal.
3. find sub-space $U$ of $R^4$ of maximal dimension, that $\forall \ \ 0 \neq x\in U,\:q\left(u\right)>0 $

I see that $$\left[q\right]_E=\begin{pmatrix}0&0&0&1\\ 0&0&-3&0\\ 0&-3&0&0\\ 1&0&0&0\end{pmatrix}$$

Is it diagnolizable or am I wrong in its representation ?
Can I express it as sum of quadratic elements at all ?
Ho do I approach to that last question ?

Comment: this is a symmetric matrix which is always diagnolizable

Comment: I tried the method, which says do raw and col elementary operations to get a diagonal matrix, and then repeat the columns operations them on the I matrix and i supposed to get P, but some why I couldn't diagonalize q (maybe I missed it somehow dk).